# Chrome Updated To Version 106 - Selenium No longer works

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My code was working 2 days ago and then chrome updated. I have no idea how to address the below issue, though the specific problem is very clear.

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 104
> Current browser version is 106.0.5249.91 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Can you help?

Comment: either update your chromedriver version to v106.x.  OR set system environment variable: "webdriver.chrome.disableBuildCheck", "true"

Comment: You can also use the excellent WebDriverManager which will manage the driver version for you: Java: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager Python: https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by two steps

1. checked the verison of chrome by going to settings > about chrome > updating version
2. Check the chrome driver download version  matching to chrome version

unzip the downloaded file and read to go

Answer (score 1):

Go to Chrome> Settings > About Chrome - check your current version.

Download the appropriate chrome driver from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads